# Reading a csv file, ignoring some rows in the middle

Tags: csv, import, ssis

I'm trying to use SSIS to import a csv file. Normally it works fine, but the file in question has this format:

> ....
>   data, data, data, data, data, data, data
>   ignore, ignore
>   ignore, ignore
>   ignore, ignore
>   data, data, data, data, data, data, data
>   ...

The result is that it imports the `data` ok, but when it gets to the `ignore` lines, it'll start putting the next line of data as the rest of the expected columns until it encounters a newline.

How can I ignore the rows that don't have the required number of fields?

---

I'm using SSIS 2005.

Comment: Is a script to massage the CSV before importing it an acceptable solution?

Comment: If there's nothing built in I can use then sure, although I've never used a script component before so an example would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique I've used, although it wasn't ideal, was to read in the source data a whole row at a time, then use a script transform to test the incoming row - If the row has enough fields (Using string.split on the comma) then assign each part to the relevant output row value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136114.aspx

It's not as simple to set up, but it has worked OK for me in the past. May be a pain if you have to manually define a lot of columns for the script transform output.

Comment: I've had a go at adding a script transform component, but it looks like it only operates on input, but by the time it gets the input it's too late, the columns have already got mangled by the invalid data. For example the first row of invalid data ends with fields from the following, row (even though it's another row and should be treated as such).

Comment: Because of the above, it's erroring when it tries to truncate the last column, which actually contains all the remaining fields of the row it added to the invalid data row. So it really looks like i need to process the file before it gets to the import.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - You read in the whole row in one lot - So change your CSV source input to read the whole line as one object, pass that to your script transform, test the line as a whole has the right number of columns and if so manually split it in the script and pass the parts to the script outputs that you set up manually.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett If I've misunderstood, and your source CSV has no linebreaks on the invalid lines, then this may not work. But try reading in each line as a single 'thing' and see how that goes.